# List<dynamic> does not return structure

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

I got a public property of List<dynamic> type.

This property is getting populated with same type of objects in the list. I am using a third party reporting tool to design a report by data returned by this property.

When the List object contains data, I am able to see the required properties/structure to design the report. Whereas when there is no data I do not see any properties to create the report layout.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would help if you could give a [mcve] to show what you're trying to achieve and what you expect. If there's no data available, where would you *expect* to be able to see the structure? How are you determining the structure?

Comment: If the list is empty then the Count should be zero or the list null.  So test if((type != null) && (type.Count > 0))

Comment: 9 times out of 10 when i see the use of `dynamic`, its just bad solution to another problem that should be fixed

Comment: There is no information present if the list is empty, you will need to make it a list of something that isn't dynamic to get this, or add at least one element to the list, or figure out a completely different way to obtain the metadata than looking at the list itself.

Comment: What do you expect your header to look like when there is no element at all to get that data from? What is the "default"-metadata?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is obviously true. `dynamic` properties are evaluated at run time. If there is no data to show, there is no way to know what type of object, struct or anything else would actually go in there. So reflection is not able to determine anything about the type at that moment. (I don't have to say that using reflection on `dynamic` types is dangerous to start with, since the type can change at any time without any warning.)

The solution is to ensure there is always data so reflection can determine the types on the data provided, or preferably don't use `dynamic` at all.